# General error: 1364 Field 'gag_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Trato de almacenar  información a través de mi formulario con los siguientes modelos folder, program y gag..
Básicamente trato de registrar la información empleada para la fabricación de una pieza.
Es por eso que una carpeta(folders), tiene un programa(program), y una mordaza(gag).

La relación que existe entre ellos es la siguiente

**Modelo Folder:
->A un folder le pertence un program,
->A un folder le pertence un gag**

**Modelo Program:
->Un program tiene un folder**

**Modelo Gag:
->Un gag tiene un folder**

Model Folder

```
class Folder extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'denomination','code','observation','time'
    ];    

    public function program()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Program', 'program_id');
    }

    public function gag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Gag', 'gag_id');
    }
```

Model Program

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name_program','number_program','part_program'
   ]; 

    public function folder()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Folder');
    }
```

Model Gag

```
protected $fillable = [
        'number_gag','diameter','type_gag','category_gag'
    ];

    public function folder()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Folder');
    }
```

**Actualizado**

Trato de guardar la informacion de la siguiente manera:

FolderController: (metodo create y store)

```
public function create()
    {
        $folder = new Folder();      

        // $this->authorize('create', $folder);

        return view('admin.folders.partials.form', [
            'legajos'       => Folder::all(),
            'denomination'  => Folder::pluck('denomination', 'denomination'),        

            'folder'     => $folder
        ]);       
    }

 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();                 

                $program = Program::create($request->all());
                $gag = Gag::create($request->all());


                $program->folder()->create([
                    'denomination'  => $request['denomination'], 
                    'code'          => $request['code'],
                    'time'          => $request['time'],
                    'gag_id'        => $gag->id 
                ]);


                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }    
    }
```

Desde mi punto de vista primero creo un programa, luego una mordaza y finalmente una carpeta, donde ademas de almacenar los campos propios de folder trato de asignar program_id, gag_id, pero recibo el siguiente error:

> ```
> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'gag_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `folders` (`denomination`, `code`, `time`, `program_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (eje, 71, 00:04:25, 21, 2020-01-19 10:39:46, 2020-01-19 10:39:46))",
> ```

Formulario:

```
<div class="row">
    {!! Form::model($folder, [
        'route' => $folder->exists ? ['admin.folders.update', $folder->id] : 'admin.folders.store',   
        'method' => $folder->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
    ]) !!}  

    <div class="col-md-6">    
        <div class="box box-primary">            
            <div class="box-header with-border ">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del Legajo</h3>     
            </div>          
            <div class="box-body">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}  

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    <label>Denominación</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-industry"></i>
                        </div>               
                    <select name="denomination" id="denomination" class="form-control select2" {{{$enable}}}>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo)          
                            <option value="{{ $legajo->id }}"
                            {{ old('denomination', $folder->id) == $legajo->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                            {{ $legajo->denomination }}</option>                     
                        @endforeach  
                    </select>
                    </div>                                    
                </div>     

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('code', 'Código') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('code', $folder->id) == $legajo->id)               
                                {!! Form::text('code', old('code', $legajo->code), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'code', 'placeholder' => 'Codigo de pieza']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'code', 'placeholder' => 'Codigo de pieza']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>               

            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Datos del programa</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">   

                 <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('name_program', 'Nombre') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('name_program', $folder->program_id) == $legajo->program['id'])               
                                {!! Form::text('name_program', old('name_program', $legajo->program['name_program']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_program', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre de programa']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('name_program', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_program', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre de programa']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>     

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('number_program', 'Numero') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('number_program', $folder->program_id) == $legajo->program['id'])               
                                {!! Form::text('number_program', old('number_program', $legajo->program['number_program']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_program', 'placeholder' => 'Numero de programa']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('number_program', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_program', 'placeholder' => 'Numero de programa']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('part_program', 'Descripción') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('part_program', $folder->program_id) == $legajo->program['id'])               
                                {!! Form::text('part_program', old('part_program', $legajo->program['part_program']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'part_program', 'placeholder' => 'Descripción de programa']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('part_program', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'part_program', 'placeholder' => 'Descripción de programa']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>                 

        </div>
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Datos de mordaza</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('number_gag', 'Numero') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('number_gag', $folder->gag_id) == $legajo->gag['id'])               
                                {!! Form::text('number_gag', old('number_gag', $legajo->gag['number_gag']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Numero de mordaza']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('number_gag', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Numero de mordaza']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>    

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('diameter', 'Diametro') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('diameter', $folder->gag_id) == $legajo->gag['id'])               
                                {!! Form::text('diameter', old('diameter', $legajo->gag['diameter']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'diameter', 'placeholder' => 'Diametro de mordaza']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('diameter', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'diameter', 'placeholder' => 'Diametro de mordaza']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>     

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('type_gag', 'Tipo') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('type_gag', $folder->gag_id) == $legajo->gag['id'])               
                                {!! Form::text('type_gag', old('type_gag', $legajo->gag['type_gag']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'type_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Tipo de mordaza']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('type_gag', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'type_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Tipo de mordaza']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('category_gag', 'Categoria') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('category_gag', $folder->gag_id) == $legajo->gag['id'])               
                                {!! Form::text('category_gag', old('category_gag', $legajo->gag['category_gag']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'category_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Categoria de mordaza']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('category_gag', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'category_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Categoria de mordaza']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>            

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Tiempo de mecanizado</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">  

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('time', 'Tiempo') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    @if ($folder->exists)
                        @foreach ($legajos as $legajo) 
                            @if(old('time', $folder->id) == $legajo->id)               
                                {!! Form::text('time', old('time', $legajo->time), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'time', 'placeholder' => 'Codigo de pieza']) !!}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach  
                    @else
                        {!! Form::text('time', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'time', 'placeholder' => 'Codigo de pieza']) !!}
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>                

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}    
</div>
```

me podrian ayudar a resolver este incoveniente??, No entiendo este error

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si te entiendo si realice esa prueba posteriormente pero tengo el mismo error, quisas  mis modelos estan mal relacionados,  existe otra manera de guardar estas relaciones??

Comment: A lo que me refiero es a que para crear Folder lo puedes hacer así `$program->folder()->create([ 'denomination'  => $request['denomination'], 'code' => $request['code'], 'time' => $request['time'],  'gag_id'    => $gag->id  ]);` y que `$gag->folder()->create([ 'gag_id'  => $gag->id  ]);` no va. Eso te da el mismo error? Sería extraño pues explícitamente le estarías pasando el valor para `'gag_id'`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ puedes mirar mi actualizacion? es asi como estoy probando en este momento, sigo con el mismo error

Comment: Ahh, prueba agregando gag_id al array $fillable del modelo Folder

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ empece agregando gag_id array fillable del modelo folder , luego volvi a llenar mi formulario y me sale el mismo error pero con program_id entoces  agregue  program_id al array del modelo folder, y vuelvo a probar nuevamente y sigo con el mismo error pero ahora con program_id

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103482/discussion-between-rodrigo-ruiz-and-porloscerros-).

Comment: Pues ahí ya no me cierra, ya que Eloquent debería ocuparse de llenar ese campo https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method. Como salida, puedes agregarlo en el array que le pasas a `create()` como lo tenias antes, pero no me hace sentido, pues sería redundante.

Comment: Se que la publicacion es algo extensa, me ayudarian a resolver el error?